# Memory leak observed when dojo grid is refreshed

Tags: memory, dojo, grid, memory-leaks

I am using gridx with dojo 1.8.3 library.
 My application requires a dojo grid to be refreshed every second with the data which comes from server.

 
Following is the code to refresh grid with creating a new store for every refresh.
The result comes in xhrPost callback and gets assigned to new grid store.

```
refreshGrid(){
   if(grid.store!=null)
     grid.store.close();
   var newGridStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
                url:'',
                data:result,
                urlPreventCache: false
            });
   grid.setStore(newGridStore);
 }
```

Above function is getting called for every 2 seconds and I could see memory increase in chrome profile.
I had tried using the way to iterate through the store to delete all the items followed by adding new items but when store is updated grid gets locked.

 Which is the correct way of grid refresh in dojo?

Comment: It sounds like you want to implement a [real-time store](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/realtime_stores/).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you are doing looks sketchy, set store is the way to go unless you are refreshing specific items. The old store should eventually be deleted by the gc, but it does this delete whenever it feels like it and you will see a ramp up in memory usage until that point. In chrome you can force the garbage collector, so if you do this and your memory clears up then everything is running as intended and you may just be dealing with too much data too often.

It might also be useful to let us know what kind of performance decrease (if any) you are seeing, what your memory usage is ranging from, and what amount of data you are dealing with in your store.

Comment: Basically when application is kept running for a day , it gives stop script error, some times browser crashes.